# "normal" CSS to Boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to the responsive world and am using a template that is using bootstrap.

I have the following CSS that I would like to make responsive but I am unsure of the best way to go about it.

I have modified the following [theme](http://graphpaperpress.com/themes/onesie/)

I am wanting to move the `Onesie` title to the top of the page - I have shifted that code into the `#siteTitleBox`

In the gap to the left of the theme I have created a new div called `#text` this will show data of a random post etc

I have the location of what I want correct but I just now need help to develop it into Responsive Code.

**CSS:**

```
#siteTitleBox
{
margin: -580px 0 0 0;
height:150px !important;
}
#text{
margin:-568px 0 0 -135px;
width:530px;
height: 100% !important;  
border:1px solid transparent;  
color: #ffffff;
background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .4 );
border-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .9 ); 
}
#text p{
margin: -65px 5px 0 5px;
}
#text h3{
 margin:0 0 0 5px;
}
#siteTitleBox h1 a:hover{
color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="siteTitleBox">Page Title</div>
<div id="text"><p>ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC </p>
```

Comment: For a start, get rid of those huge negative margins and !important modifiers.  Then add some width based media queries.  If you want more specific advice, you'll have to show some html.

Comment: I don't even understand what the question is and based on what

Comment: @Fabio I was in the process of changing the question and I have now done so

Comment: The way to design responsively is to combine fluid design and responsive and start with small viewports first. Outside of all media queries, you create the common to all viewports, inside the min-width media queries, from smallest to largest, you put in your floats and styles appropriate for that viewport. Start learning to use percentages for sizing as much as you can.

Comment: Not a responsive theme, when I size it up, the middle doesn't stay middle, there's inline styles of 1074px height. You don't need to over write the css, just remove the vertical-align:middle. Also, this is a better place to start: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/ - it's responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u want use best way in responsive.don't use pixel base width,size.use % based

```
width:50%
```

still you want use pixel based declaration then use different media queries in css or in html
like

**css**

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait){
 #text{
width:30px;} 
}`
@media screen and (device-width: 450px) and (device-height: 100px) and (orientation:portrait){
 #text{
width:320px;} 
}`
```

**html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 450px)" href="phone.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 760px)" href="tablet.css" />
```